# Есть ли смысл ставить индекс на 2 столбца?

Tags: postgresql

Есть таблица где есть стобцы

```
id 
type
```

И поиск ведется так

```
WHERE id = 500 AND type=2
```

Таблица состоит из 2 млн записей.
вариантов id может быть много, а вот type только 4 разных (1,2,3,4).

Вопрос в том, нужно ли создавать индекс только на столбец id либо же двойной индекс id и type? Чтобы скорость поиска была выше. Или не будет разницы?

Comment: ИМХО если общее количество полей с одинаковым `id` сколь-либо значительно, то есть смысл... иначе — нет. Да, если (id, type) принципиально уникальны, то скорей всего стоит создать UNIQUE всё равно.

Comment: *type только 4 разных (1,2,3,4)* Если пара (id,type) НЕ уникальна, и есть дополнительные условия отбора по этой таблице, то индекс по двум полям имеет смысл. Иначе скорее нет.